# Usage of “du coup”

Tags: expressions, sens, usage

I often come across the phrase *du coup* in the course of discussion with my French friends. What does it signify and when to use it? Some of them tend to add it in every other sentence, most often at the start!

Comment: "Du coup" is a quite French thing. I dont think it's being used in other French speaking countries (Middle East, North Africa, Guadeloupe, etc.). I used to live in Lebanon and never heard it there among local French speakers. People there would say "donc" or "dans ce cas" or just do without it - it is optional after all. When I hear native French speakers use it, I often find it superfluous and wonder why they use it so often.

Comment: I also hear this used often by a few specific people. The way they use it seems similar to how some English speakers I know say "you know" often during a conversation, but they're not asking for my feedback, it's just a filler they've adopted as part of their speech pattern. Is it possible "du coup" could be used as filler speech in French?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## En général

*Du coup*, est une locution équivalente à :

- en conséquence,
- de ce fait,
- à la suite de quoi

> Le train était annoncé avec une heure de retard, du coup Mimile alla
>   prendre un verre.

## En début de phrase

Conversation familière :

> — Tiens, ce soir, je dois passer près de chez toi !
>      — Du coup tu pourras me ramener ?
>      — Si tu quittes tôt (sous entendu : ton travail).
>      — Du coup ça l'fera pas¹.

*du coup* peut être remplacé par : **dans ce cas** (prononcé *danse k*)

---

<sub>1. *ça l'fera pas* (prononcé *ça l'fra pas*) : *on ne pourra pas le faire* : on ne pourra pas faire la route ensemble, je serai encore au travail lorsque tu partiras.</sub>

Comment: J'aurais dit "*[...] du coup, Mimile est allé prendre un verre*": le passé simple semble un peu formel avec "*du coup*", qui l'est moins.

Comment: @Bruno Exact, mais j'avais en-tête une situation plus littéraire.

Comment: @cl-r « **Sur ces entrefaites**, le sieur Emile entreprit, fantasque projet, de se désaltérer à l'envi. »

Comment: @RomainVALERI aimer les mots, les césures, débucher les trouvailles, quel plaisir!

Comment: S'agit-il de citations ou d'exemples? J'ai été repris la semaine dernière par un prof de français, selon qui _du coup_ est incorrect. Du coup, je cherche mes liaisons, parce que j'avais tendance à abuser de celle-ci.

Comment: @rds: *Du coup* est familier, mais tout à fait courant dans la langue, je serais fort curieux de savoir en vertu de quoi il serait incorrect. Mais du coup, ça me fait penser à ce que je ne l'emploie plus du tout depuis un moment…

Comment: j'ajouterais l'article présent au lien suivant : http://claudinecholletecrivain.hautetfort.com/archive/2006/09/05/tordons-le-cou-a-l-expression-du-coup.html

Comment: @Nomaru -- L'article est un peu (litote) polémique et certains commentaires contredisent valablement son argumentation linguistique ; *du coup* 'il manifeste une réaction épidermique !

Comment: Du coup comme expression familière vient souvent dans une explication donnée par un premier locuteur à un deuxième locuteur. "Mais pourquoi t'es pas venu me voir? Du coup, t'aurais pu voir ta frangine aussi". Il me semble qu'ici (dans ce forum) on a du mal a accepté que la grammaire du français parlé ne ressemble pas à un article venant de la plume d'un académicien...

Comment: @Lambie - Les exemples fournis, le commentaire de 'Bruno'  contre-disent la réponde faite à 'rds'... ici, il suffit seulement de préciser le domaine de référence : soutenu, familier, parlé, argot ...

Comment: @cl-r Ce que j'avais rajouté, personne ici a signalé. J'ai le droit ou pas?

Comment: Tout commentaire qui respecte le *nétiquette* et l'esprit de la question est bienvenu :-)

Answer (score 11):

Basicaly, it's a casual variety of “so”, oriented towards consequence :

> *Something happens*
>   — **So**, does it change anything ?

As [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2959/1514) mentions, there are various ways to express the same thing in French :

[image: ngram]

And I'd mention in Québec, “*faque*”, a shortened form of “*ce qui fait que*” is *very* common **in oral speech**.

> *Faque je ne dis plus jamais « du coup », moi, maintenant.*

Comment: On a side note, I've often heard "*faque ça fait que...*", which I find pretty amusing.

Comment: @Kareen C'est fou d'entendre ça au jour d'aujourd'hui !

Comment: +1 pour le choix des requêtes. J'ai l'impression que les expressions les plus utilisées verbalement/familièrement sont les plus 'cotées', et les lignes rouge et verte indiquent une expression plus recherchée, utilisée dans les rapports, les exposés ou les formulations écrites

Comment: Quel site est à l'origine de ce graphique?

Comment: @nowox: google ngram sûrement.

Comment: @Nikana Reklawyks : En France, et je vis en France, dans le langage parlé, on entend "du coup" 10 fois par jour. On ne peut guère, aujourd'hui, le remplacer par les synonymes, les "par conséquent" etc... *Du coup*, c'est devenu une *expression*, proche du "so" en anglais. *Du coup*, upvote !