# Too many coups lead to ambiguity

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

I know what “du coup” means. What does “pour le coup” mean and how does one use it?

Comment: Réponse pour *"du coup*" : ***http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2959/848***

Comment: En français, on dirait "Trop de coups tue le coup" :)

Answer (score 3):

«**Pour le coup**» usually means ["in this instance"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/pour%20le%20coup), but it can mean ["in this case/consequently"](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/47666).

The [internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/14542/pour-le-coup/) site cautions that it is an older usage and generally poorly employed in this sense.

The TLFi [entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup) lacks a specific synonym, but seems to suggest its use as being something like "exactly for this case".

(The [Academy](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/getobject_?p.4:54./var/artfla/dicos/ACAD_1835/IMAGE/) is not very useful.)

Answer (score 1):

*Du coup* means something like "therefore, then" but is colloquial.

*Du coup, tu as gagné !* → Then, you win!

*Pour le coup* might mean various things depending on the context like *This time*, *At once*.

*Pour le coup, tu as raison !* → This time, you are right!

Comment: _Larousse_ le marque _familier_ aussi. Je pensais que c'était un équivalent de l'anglais FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

J'ajouterai que "Pour le coup" porte une connotation d'unicité(uniqueness) ou d'intensité. Pour reprendre l'exemple d'au dessus, "Pour le coup, tu as raison." : Cette fois-ci tu as raison. Pas les autres fois.

Alors que du coup, est un simple constat.